# passing serialized jquery data to php, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I currently have a form with inputs and name attributes.

I'm able to get what I needed through jquery:

```
 var inputValues= $('.myForm').serialize();
```

if I `alert(inputValues)`, I get what I needed, (like form GET variables: `categories=examplevalue&name=examplename&email=exampleemail`)

Now, I'm trying to pass it to PHP with ajax, like so (**ajax.js**)

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "myfile.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "inputs="+inputValues
            }).done(function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
```

In my **PHP** i have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['inputs'])){
   echo $_POST['inputs'];
}
```

I assume that it would alert out bunch of variables depending on my form, but it only echo's out the first name variable which is `categories`

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serialize()` generates a query string (`foo=bar&baz=yikes`) format that cannot be assigned to a single parameter (`inputs=...` in your case).

In your `$.ajax` call, remove `inputs=` and just use `inputValues` alone. This would allow you to get the individual variables in your form using `$_POST['myvar']`.

Comment: I think this is what helped me out, I see how I can pass it through now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. assignment of data:

   ```
   $.ajax({
           url: "myfile.php",
           type: "POST",
           data:  $('.myForm').serialize()

   }).done(function(data){
           alert(data);
   });
   ```

   Prefix field names with with inputs. Like `<input name="x"/>` becomes `<input name="inputs[x]"/>`.
2. Displaying arrays in php:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['inputs'])){
      var_dump($_POST['inputs']);
   }
   ```

   (`echo` would just print `Array` when its not a scalar value).

### Update

IF, Lior Cohen is right and your server does not recognise the field name notation (not the case with default php settings) then you can use this simple workaround:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $POST);
```

and then use `$POST` instead of `$_POST`. Be aware though that `$POST` won't be super-global.

Comment: This method does not always work (depending on the web server being used, PHP settings, etc). Test thoroughly on your intended environments if you're planning on using this.

Comment: var_dump($_POST['inputs']) dose not work correctly because the form should be include of <select> or textarea or...

Comment: @hamidreza66 var_dump makes extensive reports on (almost) any data type available in `php`. What do you mean it does not work correctly?

Comment: If i have a select element in my form, if(isset($_POST['inputs'])){...} dose not return select values, even you should check input, not inputs

Comment: @hamidreza66 `<select name="inputs[selectVal]">...</select>` will set `$_POST['inputs']` when submitted. Therefore `isset` will return true. Where is the problem?

Comment: Oh, i make mistake, but if the form has different element name? for example <select name="mySelect">

Comment: @hamidreza66 therefore i said that for this work all fields must be prefixed with `inputs[`...`]`. I even gave examples.

Comment: Oh :D you're true, I don't read what u say, Just i see your code :), sorry

Comment: @LiorCohen added an update for the eventuality, but do you know what kind of php ini directive would cause such behaviour?

Comment: What if I have many if isset variables passing in the same file? How does it know that I'm looking for specific inputs?

Comment: @andrewliu I am sorry, but your quetion doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-serializepost/

Sorry about formatting I will fix when on computer

```
 (function($) {

        $.fn.serializePost = function() {

var data = {};

var formData = this.serializeArray();

for (var i = formData.length; i--;) {

var name = formData[i].name;

var value = formData[i].value;

var index = name.indexOf('[]');

if (index > -1) {

name = name.substring(0, index);

if (!(name in data)) {

data[name] = [];

}

data[name].push(value);

}

else

data[name] = value;

}

return data;

};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at what you're sending to the PHP... if you concatenate 'inputvalues=' with the serialzied form, you wind up sending the following to the PHP:

```
inputs=categories=examplevalue&name=examplename&email=exampleemail
```

So, yeah... it is going to be confused.  : )

Instead, just do this in the jQuery:

```
data:inputValues
```

You'll need to change your acceptance conditions on the post.

You can also serialize your data into JSON and deserialize it, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I do not tested this code but i think it works

```
    var inputValues= $('.myForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "myfile.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: inputValues,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            // or use: console.log(data); /*you need firebug to log*/
        }
    });
```

// and php

```
if(isset($_POST)){
   var_dump($_POST);
}
```